# 422 Unprocessable Entity Error. I tried upload Excel file to import data but it is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation, vuejs2, laravel-8

> This is my code, i use vuejs and laravel. The function I am doing is both saving the Course and also importing the Excel file to get the data in the file. But when saving the Course is normal, but when it comes to running the validate excel file line, the error is not received. Even though I gave it a name and console.log came out. Can you help me fix it? Thank you so much.

**Component - template tag**

```
<form @submit.prevent="store()" @keydown="form.onKeydown($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Courses</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="education_program_course" v-model="form.education_program_course">
        <option value="" disabled selected="">Select option</option>
        <option value="" disabled>-------</option>
        <option v-for="course in courses" :key="course.course_code" :value="course.course_code">{{ course.course_name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Excel File</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_data" name="file_data" ref="fileupload" @change="onFileChange">
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer text-right">
     <button :disabled="form.busy" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-1" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Component - script tag**

```
export default: {
    data() {
       return {
        file_data: "",
        form: new Form({
          education_program_course
      }),
    },
    methods: {
      onFileChange(e) {
           this.file_data = e.target.files[0];
      },  
      store() {     
            this.form.busy = true;
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file_data', this.file_data);
            this.form.post('../../api/admin/program/education', formData, {
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                })
                .then(res => {
                if(this.form.successful){
                    this.$snotify.success('Sucessful!');
                    this.form.clear();
                    this.form.reset();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.$snotify.error(err.response.data.errors.file_data[0]);
            });
        },
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'education_program_course' => ['required'],
    'file_data' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:xls,xlsx']
]);
$program = new EducationProgram();
$program->education_program_course = $data['education_program_course'];
$path = $request->file($data['file_data'])->getRealPath();
Excel::import(new ProgramDetailImport, $path);
```

Comment: @guyg i just send file_data to formData because education_program_course is already available in this.form

Answer (score 1):

You should append 'education_program_course' on your formdata.

```
    formData.append('education_program_course', this.form.education_program_course);
```

Comment: i think education_program_course is already available in this.form

Comment: check your validation error from browser network console

Comment: I checked and it says validation required error. But when I check `console.log(this.file_data)` it still shows that file data.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Change change at script tag -> `store()`

from:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_data', this.file_data);
```

to:

```
if(document.getElementById("file_data").files[0]){
   this.form.file_data = document.getElementById("file_data").files[0];
}
```

Adding `file_date` in `form: new Form` and remove `formData` in `this.form.post`.

Comment: Can you clarify your explanation? What do you mean by "Change change at script tag -> store()`? That doesn't seem to be reflected in your actual suggestion. Am I misunderstanding? If so, others might as well.